# How to set same "STRING" as start and end reference to copy the message within those references?

Tags: vba, string, outlook

I have an email that has a long body. I want to send part of the email body by setting a starting "STRING" reference and an ending same "STRING" reference.

Let's say the "STRING" = "Good day!"

Whenever the macro set the first string "Good day!" in the email body, I want the next "Good day!" string to be the ending reference without searching/finding another "Good day!" string so that the message within those two references can be copied to be sent as a new mail.

I found this code that uses a UNIQUE string but I need the next string occurrence only after the first string reference.

http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=985

- With this on hand, I'm thinking just to replace the 2nd "Good day!" with a UNIQUE string so that I can use this code but I still don't know how to search/find for the 2nd occurrence of the same string.

Comment: Use the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) . Find the first and use that as the starting position to find the second.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approximation of an email's 'body text'

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque fringilla mi et aliquam ornare. Sed et dolor posuere, feugiat mi ac, mattis augue. **Good day!** Ut lorem sem, pulvinar a erat a, tempus congue lorem. Nulla semper cursus ante ac euismod. Sed rutrum odio a nulla consectetur, scelerisque lacinia risus consectetur. **Good day!**  Fusce sit amet vulputate lorem, eu aliquam diam.

Pass that text as a string through this function.

```
Function partial_body(sBDY As String, Optional sFND As String = "Good day!", Optional bINCL As Boolean = False)
    Dim s As Long, f As Long
    s = InStr(1, sBDY, sFND, vbTextCompare) - ((Not bINCL) * Len(sFND))
    f = InStr(s + 1, sBDY, sFND, vbTextCompare) + (bINCL * Len(sFND))
    partial_body = Trim(Mid(sBDY, s, f - s - (bINCL * Len(sFND)) * 2))
End Function
```

Result for `partial_body(<body>)`

> Ut lorem sem, pulvinar a erat a, tempus congue lorem. Nulla semper cursus ante ac euismod. Sed rutrum odio a nulla consectetur, scelerisque lacinia risus consectetur.

Result for `partial_body(<body>, "Good day!", True)`

> Good day! Ut lorem sem, pulvinar a erat a, tempus congue lorem. Nulla semper cursus ante ac euismod. Sed rutrum odio a nulla consectetur, scelerisque lacinia risus consectetur. Good day!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. But, I can't understand the language you're using, I tried translating it but google translate doesn't translate it right.

Comment: The text is unimportant. It is simply to provide some text that had your *keywords* inserted into it so that you could see the options from pulling out portions of text. If you are curios then look up [Lorum Ipsem](http://lipsum.com/) placeholder text for a brief history.